# Wix React Native Navigation V2 initialise Stack with more screens

Tags: wix-react-native-navigation

I am new to RNN V2. I was going through the documentation and I was testing some of the layouts.

One thing that I found confusing when reading about the stack is (from the documentation) - Support children layouts of any kind. A stack can be initialised with more than one screen, in which case the last screen will be presented at the top of the stack. -

I have done it but I do not understand the purpose of it.

The very last screen in the array is presented at the top of the stack with a back button that lets you navigate back to the the very first screen in the array. I don’t see how it can be useful. I am sure I am missing something and I would appreciate if anyone with some experience with it  could elaborate it more.
[last screen in array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbBLE.png)
[Stack description](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/layout-types?id=stack)

Answer (score 0):

This is useful for Push Notifications flows.
Imagine a social app where a user can be a member of several groups. The user is using the app and is currently scrolling through the feed of **group A**. While scrolling he receives an in-app notification about a reply he got to a his post in **group B**.

In such case, if the user clicks on the in-app notification, we can show a modal with a stack which contains two children:

- Child 1 (Not visible) - **Group B** feed screen
- Child 2 (Top child, visible) - Post screen where the user can read his post and the reply

This is useful because once we navigates back, he'll remain in Context of the post since he'll see Group B's feed (home) screen.
Navigating back again, will close the modal and the user returns to where he left off.

Another reason why this is possible - while designing the api we didn't want to limit out users. We wanted to think of layouts as generic building blocks which you could mix and match according to your product needs.

Comment: HI, thanks for answering. Now it makes more sense. Really appreciate your explanation.